# Find a, b given a function satisfies the Laplace equation.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The function is $f(x,y,z)=e^{ax+by}\cos(5z)$. I am supposed to find a and b given that it satisfies Laplace equation: $f_{xx}+f_{yy}+f_{zz}=0$

So, I found each derivative and replaced it back into the equation:

$\cos(5z)e^{ax+by}(a^2+b^2-25)=0$

So, all I can say is that $a^2+b^2=25$ which doesn't solve the problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: why not consider  $cos(5*z)=0$?if it is related  to $a,b$ only say that equation is all circle with radius $5$  and center  $0,0$

Comment: https://www.google.ge/search?q=x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D25&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=u0x_UrCKL6e60QWI14HQDQ&ved=0CCUQsAQ&biw=1280&bih=619#facrc=_&imgrc=KoBKJ1kyG9EjRM%3A%3BxuXVPENRxRGUmM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.mathman.biz%252Fimages%252Fx2%252B4y2%253D25.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.mathman.biz%252Fhtml%252Fgraphx2%252Bky2%253D25.html%3B2550%3B3509

Comment: If we consider that cos(5z) is equal to zero then aren't we changing the initial function to zero?

Comment: first of all we  are evaluating $cos(5*z)=0$ after derivative,so we are just  trying to find ciritical points,but because they have asked for  $a$ and $b$,it is not necessary in this time,sorry i have misread question,for the equation $x^2+y^2=25$

Comment: points could be (3,4),(4,3),(-3,-4),(-3,4),(-4,3),(4,-3),(-4,-3),(0,5),(0,-5),(5,0),(-5,0)

Comment: So, the solution has multiple values--all of which that lie on the circle with radius 5 and center 0,0.

Comment: see update  comment,it has finite solution in real numbers

Comment: How can there be a finite-number of solutions to $a^2+b^2=25$. Are there any restrictions I am missing?

Comment: ,look  $a^2+b^2=25$ is all $a,b$ which satisfy this equation,they meant  real numbers i  think,so  you have to take all  integer which satisfy  this equation,there of course exist complex numbers too,but you dont need it here,just can you tell me all  numbers which sastisfy  $x^2+y^2=25$?

Comment: I understand what you mean. You already stated all integer solutions. Thanks

Comment: see my answer,please

Comment: see please answer on your previous question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y,z)=e^{ax+by}\cos(5z)$.
let us find derivatives  seperately

1.$f_{x}=a*e^{ax+by}\cos(5z)$

2.$f_{xx}=a^2*e^{ax+by}\cos(5z)$

3.$f_{yy}=b^2*e^{ax+by}\cos(5z)$

4.$f_{z}=-5*e^{ax+by}\sin(5z)$

5.$f_{zz}=-25*e^{ax+by}\cos(5z)$

not  if we arrange similar terms we get  the same as you got it

$\cos(5z)e^{ax+by}(a^2+b^2-25)=0$

clearly solution is  all $a,b$ which satisfy this solution  and they  are

$(-3,-4)$,

$(-3,4)$,

$(-4,-3)$,

$(-4,3)$,

$(3,4)$,

$(4,3)$,

$(-5,0)$,

$(0,-5)$,

$(0,5)$,

$(5,0)$
that is all.good lucks

Comment: Of course, as we said previosuly this is only if $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: exactly,you are right,as a geometry yes that is all point  which lies in circle with radius $5$ and center $(0,0)$

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could take a look at this problem as well: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550047/directional-and-partial-derivatives. Its been days now and no one has been able to answer it . I was wondering if you know how to tackle it?

Comment: that is chain rule

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: so now ask again and that that if  partial derivative of $x$ with respect to  $z$ is something ,they how can i find partial derivative of  $z$ with respect to $x$

Comment: Can you show me hows its done using the chain rule?

Comment: sure  suppose  that f is function of  u,which itself is function of   x,then $f_{x}=f_{u}*u_{x}$

Comment: If that is so then what is the significance of the gradient vector(not having any zero elements and the function being equal to 100?

Comment: it somehow will help you,because gradient vector is  sum of its partial derivatives,also because this  function  is equal constant,its gradient equal to zero,so it somehow should be related to each other,sorry i am bussy now and cant go deeply in problem,try to repost this question again

Comment: Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: try it,it will help you and consider also chain rule principles,can you  accept also my answer,just for  increasing  reputation :D,thanks my friend,by the way i will return this question and will post answer if nobody will answer it

Comment: i found answer already, i will pot it